# Turn off anti-aliasing for drawing to bitmap in WPF

Tags: wpf, drawing, antialiasing

I rendering text to bitmap using WPF. I would like to turn off anti-aliasing, I mean I want the pixels be white or black. But the text is still blured, some pixels are even grey.

Here is my code. Some lines are probably not needed.

```
RenderTargetBitmap bm = new RenderTargetBitmap(bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight, dpiX, dpiY, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

DrawingVisual drawing_visual = new DrawingVisual();

RenderOptions.SetEdgeMode(drawing_visual, EdgeMode.Unspecified);            
RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(drawing_visual, BitmapScalingMode.Linear);

RenderOptions.SetEdgeMode(bm, EdgeMode.Unspecified);
RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(bm, BitmapScalingMode.Linear);

DrawingContext drawing_context = drawing_visual.RenderOpen();            

FormattedText ft = new FormattedText("my text", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Windows.FlowDirection.LeftToRight, typeface, fontSize, Brushes.Black);
        drawing_context.DrawText(ft, new Point(0, 0));

drawing_context.Close();
bm.Render(drawing_visual);
```

**Rendered image:**

[image: blured image]

To check the solution, you can download source code from GitHub:

```
https://github.com/qub1n/Font-rendering.git
```

Comment: Text deserves special treatment with WPF. Maybe you should try TextOptions.TextFormattingMode and/or TextRenderingMode  instead: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/text/2009/08/24/wpf-4-0-text-stack-improvements/

Comment: TextFormattingMode didn't solved it and TextRenderingMode does not contains setting without anti-aliasing.

Comment: Are you interested by screen visualization or bitmap (file like .png) creation? They are quite different.

Comment: Especially in bitmap, I want to export it.

Comment: How about setting `EdgeMode` to `Aliased`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important notion here is the [TextRenderingMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.textoptions.textrenderingmode.aspx). It's logical, since you don't want anti-aliased text, you must set the TextRenderingMode to [Aliased](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/text/2009/08/24/wpf-4-0-text-stack-improvements/). The difficulty is where to put it...

I recommend you create a DrawingImage instead, like this, as the start object (use it as your canvas source, instead of a bitmap):

```
    public static DrawingImage CreateImage(int heightPixel, Typeface typeface, double fontSize, string text)
    {
        var group = new DrawingGroup();
        using (var context = group.Open())
        {
            var ft = new FormattedText(text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, FlowDirection.LeftToRight, typeface, fontSize, Brushes.Black, null,
                TextFormattingMode.Display); // this is the important line here!
            context.DrawText(ft, new Point(0, 0));
        }

        return new DrawingImage(group);
    }
```

Note the also important [TextFormattingMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.textoptions.textformattingmode.aspx) value set to [Display](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.textformattingmode.aspx). If you don't do this and keep the default value ([Ideal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.textformattingmode.aspx)), then you'll still have anti-aliasing.

Now, for rendering on the display, you will have to use TextRenderingMode on a Visual element, so in your example, on your canvas element:

```
    <controls:ImageCanvas ... TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="Aliased" ... />
```

and for rendering on a bitmap, you'll have to create an intermediary Visual, here an [Image](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.aspx) object, so you can apply the TextRenderingMode on it:

```
    public static void SaveToFile(string filePath, DrawingImage drawing)
    {
        var image = new Image { Source = drawing };
        image.Arrange(new Rect(new Size(drawing.Width, drawing.Height)));

        // this is the important line here!
        TextOptions.SetTextRenderingMode(image, TextRenderingMode.Aliased);

        // note if you use a different DPI than the screen (96 here), you still will have anti-aliasing
        // as the system is pretty automatic anyway
        var bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)drawing.Width, (int)drawing.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        bitmap.Render(image);

        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap));
            encoder.Save(fileStream);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that setting `TextOptions.SetTextRenderingMode()` on `drawinVisual` does not work. Accepted answer still has aliasing issues in the bitmap generated (it's better with `TextFormattingMode.Display` but still not exactly unaliased).

What worked for me was setting internal property on drawing visual:

```
    var visual = new DrawingVisual();
    var property = typeof(Visual).GetProperty("VisualTextRenderingMode", 
                BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

    property.SetValue(visual, TextRenderingMode.Aliased);
```